# How to replicate all changes from source to destination db using debezium and confluent-sink-connector running on docker

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium, cdc

The below code is my Dockerfile for Kafka-connect-JDBC and MySQL-driver

```
FROM debezium/connect:1.3
ENV KAFKA_CONNECT_JDBC_DIR=$KAFKA_CONNECT_PLUGINS_DIR/kafka-connect-jdbc
ENV MYSQL_DRIVER_VERSION 8.0.20
ARG KAFKA_JDBC_VERSION=5.5.0
RUN curl -k -SL "https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-${MYSQL_DRIVER_VERSION}.tar.gz" \
    | tar -xzf - -C /kafka/libs --strip-components=1 mysql-connector-java-8.0.20/mysql-connector-java-${MYSQL_DRIVER_VERSION}.jar
RUN mkdir $KAFKA_CONNECT_JDBC_DIR && cd $KAFKA_CONNECT_JDBC_DIR &&\
    curl -sO https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/kafka-connect-jdbc/$KAFKA_JDBC_VERSION/kafka-connect-jdbc-$KAFKA_JDBC_VERSION.jar
```

```
docker build . --tag kafka kafka-connect-sink
```

Below is my source db json

```sh
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" 192.168.99.102:8083/connectors/ -d '{
    "name": "inventory-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "mysql",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "debezium",
        "database.password": "dbz",
        "database.server.id": "184054",
        "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
        "database.include.list": "inventory",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.inventory"
    }
}'
```

Below is my destination db sink json

```sh
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" 192.168.99.102:8083/connectors/ -d '{
    "name": "inventory-connector-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.104:3306/pk?useSSL=false",
        "connection.user": "pavan",
        "connection.password": "root",
        "topics": "dbserver1.inventory.customers",
        "table.name.format": "pk.customers",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "auto.evolve": "true",
        "delete.enabled": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.fields": "id",
        "pk.mode": "record_key",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
        "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "rewrite"
    }
}'
```

```sh
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" 192.168.99.102:8083/connectors/ -d '{
    "name": "inventory-connector-sink-addresses",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.104:3306/pk?useSSL=false",
        "connection.user": "pavan",
        "connection.password": "root",
        "topics": "dbserver1.inventory.addresses",
        "table.name.format": "pk.addresses",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "auto.evolve": "true",
        "delete.enabled": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.fields": "id",
        "pk.mode": "record_key",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
        "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "rewrite"
    }
}'
```

with this configuration i need to subscribe to each topic but problem is i had 100+ tables to get replicate in destination db is there anyway i can do it in single json configuration so that i can subscribe to all topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`topics`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/connect/sink-connect-configs.html#topics) (or [`topics.regex`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/connect/sink-connect-configs.html#topics.regex)) property to define the list of topics to consume and [`table.name.format`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html#data-mapping) property of JBDC Sink connector or [`RegexRouter`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html) SMT (or combine them) to override destination table names:

```sh
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" 192.168.99.102:8083/connectors/ -d '{
    "name": "inventory-connector-sink-addresses",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.104:3306/pk?useSSL=false",
        "connection.user": "pavan",
        "connection.password": "root",
        "topics": "dbserver1.inventory.addresses,dbserver1.inventory.customers",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "auto.evolve": "true",
        "delete.enabled": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.fields": "",
        "pk.mode": "record_key",
        "transforms": "route,unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
        "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "rewrite",

        "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
        "transforms.route.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
        "transforms.route.replacement": "pk.$3"
    }
}'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution but each table has different primary key name it is only working for tables with primary key name as "id" suppose if customers table has cust_seq as primary key it is throwing error

Comment: Leave pk.fields empty. In this case, all fields from key struct will be used